# Что означает оператор => в PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

***Вступление***

До смешного мелкий вопрос, и все же гугл плохо реагирует на спец знаки, выдавая вариации на тему "больше или равно" >=, но тут у нас какой-то переход и я не понимаю смысл (пытаюсь разобрать чужой код).

***Суть***

Есть вызов функции:

```
if not mypkg.myfunc (
    param_1 => PARAM_1,
    param_2 => PARAM_2) then
...
end if;
```

Вот и возникает вопрос, что это за морфема в месте ввода параметров, где имена параметров отличаются только регистром?

Comment: ищите по строке `oracle named parameters` по крайней мере в большинстве языков такой знак означает именно задание имени именованного параметра или что нибудь из той же оперы. первый раз вижу в оракле, но судя по выдаче гугла это то о чем я подумал

Comment: Пока в предложенных ответах не упомянается явно, как это собственно называется: positional notation vs. named notation, что быстро находится   гуглом.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

В `Oracle PL\SQL` при вызовах процедур и функций можно явно указать какому параметру какое значение передается.

```
<процедура>(<имя_парметра_2> => <значение_параметра_2>, 
            <имя_парметра_1> => <значение_параметра_1>);
```

Что это дает?

1. Если у нас есть несколько перегруженных функций, с разными типами параметров, то иногда это единственный способ вызвать нужную нам функцию.
2. Можно указывать параметры в произвольном порядке
3. Улучшает читаемость кода

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что если в параметр при вызове вписано `<p_параметр_1> => <P_ПАРАМЕТР_1>`, то `<p_параметр_1>` относится к имени параметра в вызываемой процедуре, а `<P_ПАРАМЕТР_1>` относится к вызывающей процедуре (то есть если у нас в вызывающей и вызываемой процедуре имя параметра совпадает, то не возникает путаницы).

Comment: да, правильно понимаете

Answer (score 14):

Существуют три способа задать параметры в вызове подпрограмм:

- *Positional notation* - актуальные параметры задаются в том же порядке, в котором они объявлены при декларации.
- *Named notation* - актуальные параметры задаются в любом порядке используя синтаксис: 
   `formal => actual`
- *Mixed notation* - сначала задаются параметры используя *positional notation*, затем используется *named notation* для остальных параметров.

Отличие в регистре в примере вопроса не играет никакой роли, до символа `=>` формальный параметр (formal), а после актуальный (actual). Их имена могут полностью совпадать.

*Named notation* имеет ряд преимуществ по сравнению с *positional* и *mixed notation*:

- Лучшая читаемость кода.
- Порядок указания параметров не важен и не может быть неправильным.
- Вызов подпрограммы должен быть изменён только если в декларации добавлен новый обязательный формальный параметр.
- Позволяет избежать трудно диагностируемых ошибок при нарушении порядка указания актуальных параметров, особенно если они литералы.

и является рекомендуемым для вызова подпрограмм при написании нового или рефакторинге старого кода, и особенно тех, которые поддерживаются кем-то другим.

```
create or replace procedure procParams (
    id number, id2 number := null, name varchar2, name2 varchar2 := null) 
is begin null; end procParams;
/
```

Так нужно:

```
exec  procParams (id=>1, id2=>2, name=>'name', name2=>'name2');
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

exec  procParams (name=>'name', name2=>'name2', id=>1, id2=>2);
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Так можно:

```
exec  procParams (1, 2, 'name1', 'name2');
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

exec  procParams (1, 2, 'name');
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

exec  procParams (1, name=>'name');
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

А так нельзя:

```
exec  procParams (1, name=>'name1', 'name2');
PLS-00312: a positional parameter association may not follow a named association

exec  procParams (1, 'name1', name2=>'name2');
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PROCPARAMS'

exec  procParams (1, 'name', id=>2);
PLS-00703: multiple instances of named argument in list
```

Если возникнут доп. вопросы [см. офф. документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNPLS/plsql-subprograms.htm#LNPLS00825).

Answer (score 8):

Кроме того, что сказал Viktorov в своем ответе, такое используется для передачи параметров в функцию или процедуру с необязательными параметрами. Например, у нас есть процедура с тремя параметрами:

```
create or replace procedure proc (
    param1 number, 
    param2 number default 2, 
    param3 varchar2 default 'vsem privet') is ...
```

Ее можно вызвать как

```
proc(1);
```

Тогда в процедуре `param2` и `param3` будут иметь значения по умолчанию. Если надо в `param2` использовать значение по умолчанию, а в `param3` передать какое-то значение, то единственный способ сделать это - это так:

```
proc(param1 => 1, param3 => 'Hello world!');
```

Comment: Справедливости ради, такой вариант тоже работает: proc(1, param3 => 'a'); Можно комбинировать вызов параметров по позиции и по имени, до тех пор пока соблюдается "You specify the first parameters with positional notation, then switch to named notation for the last parameters."